# What is the meaning of the "fly scene" in Breaking Bad?

Tags: plot-explanation, breaking-bad

One of the Breaking Bad episodes involves a scene with a fly. Walter is obsessed by a fly in the lab and tries to kill it in order to keep the room clean.

I was told there's a special meaning but I have no clue about it...

Comment: a fly landing on a dead walter's face in the last episode will give meaning to all this fly stuff, just like the teddy bear finally had meaning

Comment: This episode confused me. 1 fly in the lab was too many for Walter, but houses full of roaches are OK?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

According to a [review](http://blogs.wsj.com/speakeasy/2010/05/24/breaking-bad-season-3-episode-10-fly-tv-recap/) in the Wall Street Journal:

> The fly has become a symbol of the loss of control in Walt’s life, so
>   its defeat is all that’s important to him right now.

Answer (score 28):

I think it's about little things escalating to big things.  The episode starts with Walt noticing .14% of each batch coming up short.  He's detected Jesse's skimming but doesn't know it yet.  The fly represents nagging doubt.  A little minor annoying thing, which leads to a bigger thing (losing his shoe) which leads to a bigger thing (falling off the mezzanine).  What problem, little today, if neglected will escalates?  **A downfall starts tiny.**

Walt has his secret betrayal too, about Jane's death, which he almost discloses after Jesse drugs his coffee with sleeping pills.  One more candidate for Walt's undoing.

By the way, this is what is known as a **"bottle" episode**.  Small setting, small cast, small budget.  Like a fly in a bottle.

Answer (score 3):

I think the meaning of the fly was that Walt's cancer came back.
On the same episode, Jessie talked about his aunt and the raccoon that she used to see. He mentioned that even after that they killed it, his aunt kept seeing it. Some time after that, they found out she had cancer and it was one of the side-effects.

Answer (score 2):

I thought it could possibly be a role reversal. Walt was Hank constantly trying to catch the fly and obsessing with it to the point where he was hurting himself and doubting his life which is exactly what has happened to Hank through is obsession with finding Heisenberg. Also, Jessie ends up killing the fly which could possibly foreshadow Jessie killing Walt. But that's every unlikely...

Comment: Interesting idea, but I'd rather think it was *Walt* and *Jessie* who switched roles. Usually it is *Walt* who has to keep the often overly irrational and distracted *Jessie* on track and professionally concentrated on the matters. This time *Walt* was going crazy and needed to be reminded by *Jessie* that they had work to do. In light of this also remember how *Jessie* at one point asked him (rather jokingly) if he tried some of the meth in the lab, seeing that *Walt* acted like on a trip (even more so after the sleeping pills, though).

Answer (score 2):

The entire episode reminded me of the "Theatre of the Absurd," which I studied with mild frustration in college: Sartre, Camus, Pinter, Ionesco, Albee.  To paraphrase:  'man is a meaning-making animal, alive in a meaningless universe; ergo, all his efforts are absurd!'

I thought Vince gave the main actors a chance to interact for an entire episode, like Didi and Gogo in Sartre's "Waiting for Godot."

Comment: Samuel Beckett wrote "Waiting for Godot". :)