# What is the significance of the "fly scene"?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, breaking-bad

I have already consulted [the original "fly scene" thread](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/3339/21217) about this, but it doesn't exactly answer my question.

I'm asking about the "fly scene" that comes in *season five* of *Breaking Bad* when Walt is sitting in the Vamanos Pest office in *Gliding Over All* (episode 8). At the very beginning, Todd walks into the office and Walt is sitting in a chair in the middle of the room. A fly is flying around and Walt seems to either be watching it or just staring into space. Then Walt and Todd have a conversation.

Now, going off of the original thread, I'm assuming it has to do with his loss of control. But I want to think there is something more to this scene then there was to the first one in the lab.

Is there a difference here? Or is this just a kind of reminder of the theme they're pushing?

Comment: The exact reason is they had an issue with production, where they have to do a episode within 3 million to do that they used this episode.

Comment: I was so tempted with that episode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I know you've consulted your previous question and the answer provided there, I'm going to refer to that answer to (try) and answer this one.

In the Season 3 episode *Fly*, Walter states:

> "This fly is a major problem for us: It will ruin our batch, and we
>   need to destroy it and every trace of it so we can cook. Failing that,
>   we're dead. There's no more room for error, not with these people."

Now, whilst out of universe it's well known that a key driving reason for the episode was a lack of budget ([as Gilligan, the show's creator has stated in interviews](http://As%20you%20said,%20it%20was%20a%20bottle%20episode%20and%20the%20reason%20for%20doing%20a%20bottle%20episode%20is%20to%20help%20keep%20your%20schedule%20and%20stay%20on%20budget.)), in universe Walt's comments show how it symbolises the perception of losing control.

Gilligan expands on Walt's comments [in an interview with Vice](http://www.vice.com/read/i-asked-the-creator-of-breaking-bad-about-meth), stating:

> The reason in our minds that he was suffering with his own form of
>   post-traumatic stress was that he had recently learned of his
>   inadvertent responsibility in the shooting and wounding of his
>   brother-in-law, Hank. He found out about Tuco’s cousins who were out
>   to get him and he found out that Hank got in the way of their shooting
>   and found out that indeed Gus Fring gave Walt’s brother-in-law to the
>   cousins instead of Walt himself. In that moment of powerlessness, in
>   that moment of shared responsibility and that moment of realizing just
>   how culpable he was, and just how he would have to suck it up and grin
>   and bear it to this very dangerous man who he thought was a very
>   business-like, very rational man. Then he finds out this guy is
>   rational to the point that he’s almost sociopathic. “My brother-in-law
>   is now in danger and everybody is a pawn to this guy and I’m trapped
>   here and I have to grin and bear it.” It’s the old Godfather line,
>   “Keep your friends close and your enemies closer.” So we had that
>   episode in which he goes to Gus and says, “I know you essentially
>   ordered a hit on my brother-in-law, and I know why you did it, and I
>   want you to understand that I’m fine with it and I would have done the
>   same thing." Of course he wasn’t fine with it, because then he got
>   into his car and almost drove into an oncoming semi. That craziness
>   you’re speaking of really all stems from that moment. It was a
>   craziness that derives from “I’m really trapped here. I don’t like
>   this feeling of being trapped. How the hell do I get out of this? How
>   the hell do I live with this guilt?”

So clearly the fly *in the episode The Fly* symbolises a terrifying realisation on Walt's part that he is not in control and a fear of where this is leading him.

Now, relating that your question about the Season 5 episode *Gliding It Over All*, I would suggest it is to again symbolise a lack of control.

In the finale of the *previous* episode, *Say My Name*, Walter loses control and kills Mike Ehrmantraut. In the opening scene of *Gliding It Over All*, he is fully appreciating how significant what he has done is and realising that once again he has placed himself in dangerous territory.

This time though, unlike in *The Fly*, his lapse is very temporary. As soon as Todd enters, he begins to compose himself and is able to start conducting operations.

I believe this indicates that he *still* senses the loss of control (and even regret) over what he has done, but that he has come a long way from the person he was in *The Fly* and he is able to process these feelings and respond to them (in a ruthless manner).